# Is it good/bad style to use \label in preamble or package/class file?

Tags: cross-referencing, package-writing

I would like to use `\label`s to organize a package file that has become too long to be navigated by simple scrolling.

It seems that this doesn't cause any errors, but I'm not sure if that's good coding style. After all, I can't reference the preamble/package/class, isn't it?

So, is this good style, or bad style? Are there any other/better ways to organize a style file so that my editor can aid me navigating it?

Comment: I guess a large portion of this depends on your editor.  You can get around this (at least in Emacs).  Throwing labels around 1) uses those labels so an actual user in unable to and 2) dirties up the aux file.

Comment: So you'd say that because of 1) and 2) it *is* bad coding style? If you make that an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept that answer. Thanks

Comment: I'd *caution* against it by (1), but I realize that I don't even yet have enough experience with LaTeX to *know* that it dirties up the aux file (I've never looked, only deduced).  It really comes down to your editor.  *Personally*, I would classify it as an *editor* feature, not that of LaTeX, so a LaTeX solution should not be pursued.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad style.  I agree that it is the editor's responsibility to make navigation easy.  Since I use Emacs, I would suggest using (i) incremental search, (ii) `imenu` (you'd have to configure it a bit, but this is not difficult), (iii) `which-function` mode (you get the configuration for free if you do (ii)) or (iv) bookmarks (suboptimal here, but probably easier to set up), (v) folding/outline mode (don't use it, so I don't know how much set up might be needed).

Comment: Actually, since it is a package/class issue, it struck me that a *super-duper-über-cool* alternative to `docstrip` would be an `org-mode` tool doing the same, but with all org goodies, like folding sections, hyperlinks.  Org-mode already has `babel` for literate programming, and powerful export capabilities, so it might be not that difficult to make.  Anybody?

Comment: If your editor does not have the features described by others, or if you want your code to be easy to read with another editor, you can create a simple syntax via comments. E.g. `% @section: Layout`, then you can either tell your editor that `% @section` starts a new code section (with bookmarks, etc.), or search for it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think it was a silly idea from the beginning (I'm only glad that my instinct told me to doubt and ask this question). The editor should be able to help me out, and I'll see what I can get from that side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely bad style and when it works it only works by accident. There is no reference-able context set up before `\begin{document}` nor is the`aux` file opened for writing before `\begin{document}`. The reason it doesn't generate an error is that `\label` does a delayed write so that it can save the page number so the write is delayed until the first page is shipped out so in particular until after the `aux` file has been opened.

However the information saved by `\label` will always be `{}{1}` so `ref` of the label will return nothing and `\pageref` of the label will return 1, so there is no useful information  generated by the `\label` command in that position.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is bad coding style.

However, it can easily be circumvented.

A good example where this is useful is when converting `TeX` files to use the newer [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex). This has some other input mechanisms for adding `.bib` files to the search path. However, most editors rely on the old `\bibliography` macro to discover the entry.

Hence I can do this (with only one operation more)

```
% RefTeX does not read this
\addbibresource{text.bib}
\iffalse
  % RefTeX DOES read this
  \bibliography{text.bib}
\fi
```

you can employ the exact same thing in your class/package.

```
\iffalse
  \label{critical point}
\fi
```

Comment: That's an interesting workaround that would get around the discussed problems, and I will definitely try to remember the idea. But in the context of my question about good style/practice I find it quite hacky.

Comment: @uli_1973 you are quite right. It is _hacky_, however, things such as these could easily be removed (or made into comments) by simple regexps for publishing. And thereby not polluting the final result.

Answer (score 0):

For organizing stuff (and being able to find it in my longuish preamble) I just use plain LaTeX comments. E.g.

```
%% AMS stuff here
...
%% Handle page format
...
```

Using `%%` (or even `%%%%` or so) makes the comments stand out, and makes them easily searchable. Probably can persuade emacs to fold each part (or mark each piece as a fold), but not *that* complex a preamble yet...